# For $n>4$ every permutation every permutation can be written as 4-cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Prove that for $n>4$ every permutation in $S_n$ can be written as the product of 4-cycles.

Consider $\alpha=(a_1 a_2 a_3)(a_4 a_5)$ is the product of two disjoint cycles and $\alpha\in S_5$. We can write (according to a previous theorem) the following number of cycles $\alpha=(a_1 a_3)(a_1a_2)(a_4 a_5)$, which is less than 4.

**Question:**

**1)** Is $\alpha=(a_1 a_3)(a_1a_2)(a_4 a_5)$ the biggest number of cycles that can be written on this particular case? I have only learnt this technique.

**2)** How do I maximize or minimize the number of cycles for a given permutation?

Comment: A $4$-cycle is a permutation of the form $( \alpha \beta \gamma \delta)$. I think the theorem is saying every element of $S_n$ can be expressed in the form $(b_{11} b_{12} b_{13} b_{14}) \cdots (b_{k1} b_{k2} b_{k3} b_{k4})$ ?

Comment: How can you build $( \alpha \beta \gamma \delta)$ with 5 elements permutation like the one I presented? the number that follows $n>4$ is 5.
Just to clarify the notation $S_n$ means the permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ elements. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: The $4$-cycles are not required to be disjoint.

Comment: @Somos                I am considering all the possibilities, so that I can prove the preposition.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit How can you build $(\alpha\beta\gamma\delta) $
 with 5 elements permutation like the one I presented? the number that follows 
$n>4$
 is $5$. Just to clarify the notation $S_ n $ 

 means the permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ 

 elements. Thanks for your insight

Comment: @Somos Yes by $S_n$ I mean the symmetric group on $n$ elements. Every element of a permutation group can be expressed as the product of transpositions. Now $(1423)(1425)(1432)=(45)$ so every transposition can be expressed as the product of $4-$ cycles and therfore any any element of a permutation group can be expressed as a product of $4$-cycles. Thus the theorem is proved (albeit by quite a greedy algorithm).

Comment: How can I formalize that argument in order to prove the proposition? I can do it by hand to $S_5$ I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: $S_n$ is generated by $A_n$ and any odd permutation, because $A_n$ has index $2$. $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles: This is much easier to verify. And $(1234)(1243)=(132)$. By similar arguments, we've generated all $3$-cycles we need. Thus the $4$-cycles generate $A_n$. And the $4$-cycles themselves are odd permutation, thus also $S_n$ is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Every element of a permutation group can be expressed as the product of transpositions. Every transposition can be expressed as the product of $4$-cycles E.g $(1423)(1425)(1432)=(45)$ so every element of a permutation group can be expressed as a product of $4$-cycles. Thus the theorem is proved.

Comment: +1 for writing that transposition as product of $4$-cycles. I am lazy and was too impatient to find such product. So I have another indirect approach.

Answer (score 0):

For question (2) the minimum is achieved if the cycles are disjoint but there is no maximum because you can always add $(ab)(ab)$ to a composition of cycles 
 permutation unless the cycles must be disjoint.

Comment: The "maximum" question can be more fruitfully interpreted as, among all permutations of $n$ symbols, which ones require the most transpositions, and how many do they require? But I think the simple answer is that an $n$-cycle requires $n-1$, and no other permutation requires more.